# How to write Dynamic SQL for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I need to write a procedure which will have just execute statements.

Example:

```
Create Procedure dbo.allSPExecute( @id int)
as
begin

EXEC dbo.tic @day= 7,@name = 'Gname',@Type = 'Utype'
EXEC dbo.tic @day= 7,@name = 'tname',@Type = 'Utype'
EXEC dbo.gtype @day = 7,@Tname = 'UName_By',@Udept = 'Dept'

End
```

I have more than 50 statements like this.I have a Table which is Lookup:

```
ID  Name        SCol      Dcol       IOrd
1   dbo.tic     Gname     @name       1
1   dbo.tic     tname     @name       2
1   dbo.tic     Utype     @Type       1
1   dbo.tic     Utype     @Type       2
2   dbo.gtype   UName_By  @Tname      1
2   dbo.gtype   Dept      @Udept      1
```

Is there a way so that If i pass ID then it will take the values from the Lookup table and execute the procedure. Can anyone help?

EDIT: Changed the Data from Lookpup table and Create Procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution that does not need cursors. I am using FOR XML keyword to concatenate strings together. I am doing this in two places - once for concatenating the list of parameters, and once for concatenating all the individual exec statements. I haven't tested this though, but i think this should be much faster than using cursors

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.allSPExecute( @id INT ) 
AS  
BEGIN   
  DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX);   
  SELECT @query =   (
    SELECT ExecPart + ' ' + SUBSTRING(Params,2,LEN(Params)) + CHAR(10)
    FROM
    (
      SELECT 
        ExecPart ='EXEC ' +(SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @id) ,
        Params = (SELECT ', ' + Dcol + ' = ' + Scol 
                  FROM MyTable t1 WHERE ID = @id AND t1.IOrd = t.IOrd FOR XML PATH(''))
      FROM MyTable t
      WHERE ID = @id
      GROUP BY IOrd
    ) t
    FOR XML PATH('')   
  ) 

  EXEC (@query) 
END
```

Comment: It works fine but it wont work if we have same ID's for Different Name. If that's the case what can we do?

Comment: I have used cursor to solve that Problem now it's working Thank you so much

Comment: 'Name' is the name of the stored proc to execute right? so what does it mean when you have the same ID for 2 different names? does it mean that you have to execute both the stored procs one after the other with the same parameters?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest solution - make your stored proc like this:

```
Create Procedure dbo.allSPExecute( @id int)
as

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'USE MyDB'

SELECT @SQL = @SQL +
'EXEC ' + t.Name + ' @day = 7,' + t.Dcol + ' = ''' + t.Scol + ''
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.id = @ID

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: @JNK Please refer to my Edited Question. The answer you gave me works only if I have one parameter not if I have multiple Parameters

Comment: @Sam - your edited criteria make no sense.  There's no rhyme or reason as to which fields go to which parameters.  You need to give me some more info.  How am I supposed to know that the third row for `id` 1 applies to both the other rows as a second parameter?

Comment: Going off of @JNK's answer, What is the relationship between rows 1, 2, & 3 for `dbo.tic`? If each row is a call to the proc, this answer works fine. You may need to change how your data is stored to have multiple columns dictating which parameters to call the proc with.

Comment: @JNK sorry for not giving enough Info. I have added another column to the table which says Iord so based on that we can determine. Please refer to my edited question. Sorry for the confusion again

Comment: @Brent Please refer to my Edited Question

Comment: @SAM - will there ever be an `IOrd` over `2`?

Comment: @JNK Yup it can go upto 10 for some of the procedures

Comment: @Sam - there's not an easy way to do what you need to do.  Are there **ANY OTHER CRITERIA**?  Please consider posting a complete question next time so we don't need to go through 15 revisions :)

Comment: @JNK sorry there are no other criteria. I will post complete question from next time. So there is no other way other than writing statements

Comment: @SAM - there's a way but it is more complicated.  Basically you need to create a list of groups based on `ID, IOrd` and execute each one of those individually

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cursor example written from scratch and untested:

```
declare @dynsql as nvarchar(300)
declare @tname as nvarchar(100)
declare @tscol as nvarchar(100)
declare @tdcol as nvarchar(100)

set @dynsql = ''

declare ticker as cursor for select Name, SCol, DCol from Lookup
open ticker
fetch next from ticker into @tname, @tscol, @tdcol

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

set @dynsql = 'EXEC ' + @tname + ' @day=7, ' + @tdcol + '=''' + @tscol + ''''

exec(@dynsql)

FETCH NEXT from ticker into @tname, @tscol, @tdcol
END

close ticker
deallocate ticker
```